# Installation best practices for a web application

Tags: java, web-applications, installation

I have a simple web application which will be running on machines which don't have internet connectivity.

I would like to support the ability to install, remove and support migration of WAR at a later stage. This would be our deployment scenario:-

1. The machines might not have Java and we would probably have to install it before deploying the application.
2. The web application (WAR) runs on top of jboss application server.
3. The application server needs to be run as a Windows service
4. The entire application will be shipped in a CD.

I don't want to spend too much time on building an installer, but what should we do support the above scenario? Are there any tools which help in handling this?

Comment: So they'll have JBoss, but not Java?

Comment: sounds like they have nothing, potentially

Comment: step 1 can be replaced by bundling ur own jvm

Comment: @glowcoder - No, we will have to install java as well as jboss

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using a MSI package with an EXE bootstrapper which supports prerequisites. This should cover all your requirements.

Regarding a setup authoring tool, it depends on what you want (free or commercial, with a GUI or with scripting etc.). You could use a Visual Studio setup project and Orca, but a commercial tool will be easier.

Comment: You can package JRE and JBoss to MSI as well, and .exe bootstrapper will not be required.

Comment: I would prefer a open source option, we don't have Microsoft tools in our environment.

Comment: WiX is always a good option. If you don't like it, you can try NSIS which is open source.